# What does the second colon in "List:D:" mean in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

In the [doc.perl6.org](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/sum), i've seen many methods like this:

```
method sum(List:D: --> Numeric:D)
```

I konw `List:D` is a type of List that is defined, but what does the colon after the `D` mean (i.e. the second one in `List:D:`)?

I found some explain in [S12-objects](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/perl6/specs/master/S12-objects.pod):

> =head2 Invocants
>
> Declaration of the invocant is optional.  You may always access the
>   current invocant using the keyword `self`.
>   ...
>   To mark an explicit invocant, just put a colon after it:
>
> ```
> method doit ($x: $a, $b, $c) { ... }
> ```

but I don't understand， it's somewhat strange at first glance.

Comment: See also GitHub Perl6 doc issue [1121](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1121): Document method invocant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default methods have an invocant of `self`

So both of these would be equivalent:

```perl6
method foo (        $a ){…}
method foo ( \self: $a ){…} # generates warning
```

So expanding the first example out to what it is sort-of short for

```perl6
method sum( List:D \self: --> Numeric:D ){…} # generates warning
```

Basically you write it that way if you want to specify the type of the invocant (first argument) to a method, but just want to use `self` rather than specify a new variable.

---

The reason it uses the `:` to split up the invocant from the rest of the parameters is to simplify the common case where you don't specify the invocant, or type of the invocant.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a sub with a basic type constraint like this:

```
sub testB (Str $b) { say $b; }
```

then you can call it with an actual instance of the type in question as well as with the type object itself:

```
> testB("woo")
woo
> testB(Str)
(Str)
```

The :D is an additional type constraint, so you can only pass a "defined" instance:

```
sub testC (Str:D $c) { say $c; }
> testB(Str)
(Str)
> testC("hoo")
hoo
> testC(Str)
Parameter '$c' of routine 'testC' must be an object instance of type 'Str', not a type object of type 'Str'.  Did you forget a '.new'?
  in sub testC at <unknown file> line 1
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

More details can be found [here](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#index-entry-type_constraint_%3AD-type_constraint_%3AU-type_constraint_%3A__-Constraining_Defined_and_Undefined_Values)

Comment: I believe chenyf was asking about the second colon in the type definition, not the first. Not `Str:D`, but `Str:D:`.

Comment: That was my first thought too. I've updated the question to make it more clear.